# Apply an array containg keys iterative to a hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following array

```
["key", "key_deeper", "key_even_deeper"]
```

and a hash:

```
{ "key" => { "key_deeper" => { "key_even_deeper" => "BINGO!" } } }
```

What is the shortest or most expressive way to apply the array on the hash to receive `"BINGO!"`?

---

That is for the base case, but there is also a special case where the value to a key is not only `String => Hash`, but also `String => [Integer, Hash]`.

For instance

```
["key1", "key2"]
```

on Hash

```
{"key1" => [5, {"key2" => "BINGO!" }] }
```

should return again `"BINGO!"`, but an array containing only `["key1"]` would simply return `5`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use `inject`:

```
array.inject(hash) do |h, i|
  h.fetch(i){ {} }
end

# => "BINGO!"
```

The `fetch` is used to prevent a `NoMethodError` in case one of your lookup values is not present in the hash. However, in that case, it will return an empty hash. You may want to do the standard lookup instead, i.e.

```
array.inject(hash) {|h,i| h[i] }
```

**Edit:**

Here's an even shorter way to do this (I don't know if I would say it's 'more expressive', but it is shorter):

```
array.inject(hash, :[])
```

Comment: That is a great answer, I appreciate the thoroughness, however, I just noticed I have another case where this line of code is not sufficient. I have added a special case for my problem into the question. Of course this can be done by adding conditional statements in the block, but it gets really messy, do you have an idea on that?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the original answer a little bit for your second version of question:

```
array.inject(hash){ |h,i| h[i].is_a?(Array) ? h[i].last : h[i] }
```